# gsutil performance downgraded when 'slice download' enabled

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to download a 2G tarball from GCS into a docker container that is running in a cluster

I am able to get 10M-15M/s downloading speed when 'slice download' is disabled, but when I enable 'slice download', the download speed dropped to 6M/s, what could be the reason? I have parallel_thread_count and parallel_process_count set to 2 for this case. I already tried other values for parallel_thread_count and parallel_process_count, it would only cause performance downgrade compared to single-thread mode.

Comment: Did you see the comments about performance at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#sliced-object-downloads ?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Yes, I did, I am using SSD which means that disk seek time won't be a problem.  So I am wondering what could be the problem...

Comment: What gsutil command are you executing? Try limiting the number of threads to force the system to use multiple processes instead. An example of a correct command is ---> $ gsutil -o 'GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1' -o 
'GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8' cp gs://bukket/fileSRC.dat 
./localDST.bin

Comment: @SamuelN I just ran "gsutil cp gs://XXX tmp.tar.gz", but I set parallel_thread_count and parallel_process_count in .boto file.  I just tried your suggested command "gsutil -o 'GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1' -o 'GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8 cp ...".  I still observe performance downgrade

Comment: Glad you gave it a shot. I'm starting to wonder if this is related to a known issue. Is this a Windows machine? Are you using a local or regional SSD and did you get the same results from testing in another machine (perhaps Linux machine)? Let me know when you can. I may have to open an Issue Tracker for you.

Comment: @SamuelN I just found out that there is a cpu limit on my running docker container, after I increased the cpu, the performance improved a lot, but there is only 10-15% speedup with 3 processes compared to a single process though, maybe there are other limitations that throttle the performance. BTW, I am using linux image

Comment: @tiancai yes, as far as I know gsutil throttles the connection. But that's as much as I know about that.

Comment: Hi, @SamuelN, I have another issue with the memory usage of gsutil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797730/gsutil-uses-a-lot-of-memory-when-download-multiple-files-with-a-lot-of-processes
Can you take a look when you have cycles, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether this is a Windows or Linux instance, there is a CPU limit on the running docker container, so you can improve performance by increasing the CPU. But note that gsutil throttles the connection based on the upper bound of the network.

You can break up the slices to achieve [best performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas) like so:

$ gsutil -o 'GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1' -o 'GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8' cp gs://bukket/fileSRC.dat ./localDST.bin

As of now, there is a known issue with gsutil not performing sliced object downloads on Windows instances. There is an open [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/128915622) for this.