# Gsutil uses a lot of memory when download multiple files with a lot of processes

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to download multiple files with gsutil and I notices that gsutil uses a lot of memory when downloading multiple files. (Around 1-2 GB ram when download three 2G files with 9 processes each). Is there a way to tune memory usage of gsutil?  This is kind of important to me because I am running gsutil in GKE, and a container will get killed if use too much memory (more than limit)

Another issue: it seems like gsutil can not download files with the same name in a single command (one will overwrite the other?). So I am not using the -m option. Instead I am downloading each file with a single gsutil command: 
gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1" -o "GSUtil:sliced_object_download_component_size=250M" -o "GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=9" -o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=9" cp bucket/file desFile

Comment: What GKE [container image](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managed-base-images#available_images) are you using? If you are using CentOS, switching to the Ubuntu should help.

Comment: What do you mean download files with the same name? Two objects in the bucket "Folder" can not have same names. If you copy next object with that same name to the bucket, older will be overwritten. [See object names considerations for more information](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations).

Comment: @PawelCzuczwara I actually mean files in different bucket "folders", for example, gsutil doesn't work for downloading /bucket1/path1/output  and /bucket2/path2/output in a single command since gsutil will download to output for both of them and one will overwrite another.  I am wondering if there is a way to work around this so that I can download all files in a single command.

Comment: Did you try `gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/data dir` recursive [subdirectories as described in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-tofrom-subdirectories-distributing-transfers-across-machines)

Comment: You can also try using `gsutil rsync -r data gs://mybucket/data` [as described in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)

Comment: "cp -r" and "rsync -r" doesn't quite fit my needs, the files I need to download doesn't necessarily belong to the same bucket and these two options would download a lot more other stuff as well. I guess download with multiple commands is my only option now.

Answer (score 0):

I did test download the 2GB file and changing -o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=X" changes memory consumption on Debian and Ubuntu:

- 1 parallel process: 85MB
- 5 parallel processes: 125MB
- 10 parallel
  processes: 165MB
- 50 paraller processes: 310MB

If you have kernel panic issues on GKE using gsutil with CentOS [container image](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managed-base-images#available_images), switching to Ubuntu image should help.

If the memory consumption is too high for 3 files simultaneous download, you can consider using only 1 or 2 downloads.

There are also known issues of [high memory usage with GKE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/503)

Comment: I am using ubuntu for container image and I am experiencing around twice the ram usage compared to your results when download a 2G file with command:
gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1" -o "GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=X" -o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=X" cp bucket/file . 

I am wondering why gsutil consumes different amount of ram under different environment...

Comment: My first test was on Debian, now I did try it on Ubuntu and got very similar results. What Google Cloud SDK are you using? I'm using 252.0.0 with gsutil 4.39

Comment: Hi, I don't have Google Cloud SDK installed in my env, my gsutil is 4.38.   Do you specify "GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1" in your command, it seems like multi-process consumes much more memory than multi-thread, but better performance.